# Tikz Variable error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

Here is my minimal code using a `foreach` loop:

```
%Creation of Arduino Pins
            \foreach \x in {1,...,22}
                {\draw($(arduino.north east)!\x/25 + 2/25!(arduino.south east)$)node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:\x}](arduinoPin\x){};}
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\numpins{25}
            %Creation of Arduino Pins
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\numpins - 3}
                {\draw($(arduino.north east)!\x/\numpins + 2/\numpins!(arduino.south east)$)node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:\x}](arduinoPin\x){};}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). Missing = inserted for \ifdim.
```

Can someone help me what's going on with the variable or something?

Comment: Use `\foreach \x in {1,...,\the\numexpr\numpins - 3}`. (In principle you could also try `\foreach \x [parse=true] in {1,...,\numpins - 3}` but parse does not work very well with integers. No one can really use your example since tit is not known what this `arduino` node is. Please post a minimal working example.

Comment: Removed `circuitikz` tag, because nothing refers to it here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have some evaluated integers.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[minimum height=10cm](arduino){};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numpins{25}
    %Creation of Arduino Pins
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\the\numexpr\numpins-3}
    {\draw($(arduino.north east)!\x/\numpins + 2/\numpins!(arduino.south east)$)
     node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:\x}](arduinoPin\x){};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```